# Text Not Positioning Over Correct Images

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Stack Overflow Community,

Trying to set up a tile system that will lead to video examples, currently filled by a placeholder image. Trying to position text above the images. Here is my current problem:

[image]

**HTML**

```
<section id="video-section" class="portfolio">
    <div class="big-container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 text-center">
                <h2>Video Production</h2>
                <hr class="small">
            </div>
            <div class="container-fluid full-width has-inner"> 
                <div class="row no-gutter">
                    <div class="col-md-4 nogut">
                        <div id="image1" class="video-item">
                            <a href="https://vimeo.com/208403633">
                                <img id="portfolio1" class="img-full-width" src="img/image1.jpg">
                            </a>
                            <p class="text"> Image 1 </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 nogut">
                        <div id="image2" class="video-item">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img class="img-full-width" src="img/image2.jpg">
                            </a>
                            <p class="text"> Image 2 </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 nogut">
                        <div id="image3" class="video-item">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img class="img-full-width" src="img/image3.jpg">
                            </a>
                            <p class="text"> Image 3 </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div> 
                <div class="row no-gutter">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div id="image4" class="video-item">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img class="img-full-width" src="img/image4.jpg">
                            </a>
                            <p class="text"> Image 4 </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div id="image5" class="video-item">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img class="img-full-width" src="img/image5.jpg">
                            </a>
                            <p class="text"> Image 5 </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div id ="image6" class="video-item">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img class="img-full-width" src="img/image6.jpg">
                            </a>
                            <p class="text"> Image 6 </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <!-- /.row (nested) -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
  #video-section {
  padding: 0px;
  background: #353030;
  color: white;
}
.big-container {
  padding: 0px;
}

.containter-fluid .full-width {
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
}

.no-gutter > [class*='col-'] {
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}


.img-full-width {
  width: 100.5%;
  height: auto;
}

.video-item {
  padding: 0px;
}

 .text {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100; 
}
```

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong? Any help would be great, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To place the `.text` items inside the `.video-item` containers, they not only have to have `position: absolute` ( which you did), but also thier * containers/parent*  need to have `position: relative`.

In your case that would be the DIVs with class `.video-item`, so you should add `position: relative` to `.video-item`. And then youshould adjust the text position by adding `top` and `left` settings to `.text`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you just want to put text over an image just change text class `CSS` to

```
.text{ 
      position: relative;
      bottom: 100px;
      z-index: 100;}
```

[Here](https://css-tricks.com/text-blocks-over-image/) is an awesome article which explains how to position text block over the images.

Also [here](http://jsfiddle.net/EgLKV/3/) is an example by @xbonez.